# What is disadvantages when using websocket on mobie?

Tags: android, websocket, battery

My company wants to use WebSocket to sysnchonize data between client and server. I have just had a demo to synchonize data between client and server but Client is web client. I want to have a demo on mobie. But I also receive some questions about the disadvantages of webSocket. For example, about battery of mobie,... ?
Could you help me list some disadvantages when using WebSocket on mobie ? And Can you explain why ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`Advantages:`

Super fast, yes its true, personal experience.
For real-time app this is most suitable choice. E.g Chat application

`Disadvantage:`

Depends how you use it. 
In my case it was, I couldn't do anything to keep my httpSession alive at time-out by serve-let.

Many Telecomm companies do not support web socket well.

Works on port 443 on most telecomm network, so yes one need to use SSL secure connection.

Comment: how about battery of mobile ?

Comment: Normal usagae, no effect, its just change of protocol from Http to Web socket

Comment: What if we are replacing a polling task based on http technology to web sockets? Theoretically this should have an impact on battery life too, isn't it?

Comment: Polling is not as fast as web-socket. Plus how much one can reduce the polling inorder to achieve real time results.

Comment: Its like chatting with a refresh cycle if one is using polling, where else the demand is of real time communication